# How to spawn a new tab in same directory as previous directory?

Tags: windows-terminal

I want to simply start a new tab in the same folder as my previous tab that I was in. Is this possible, and if so how? This is with the Windows Terminal by the way.

Now if I open a new tab, it will open in home directory (which is configured in the Windows Terminal's settings page).

Comment: Looks like this is now supported. CTRL+SHIFT+D duplicates the current tab. Also see Settings > Actions for the list of key bindings.

Comment: Can't post an answer now since it's closed but check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/new-tab-same-directory

Comment: @YRH has already said what I was going to say here! But I also want to add that **recently a new option has been added in the Terminal app settings exactly for this very purpose.** Enable it this way: **Settings -> Desired Profile (e.g., Powershell, or Pwsh, or etc.) -> Starting directory -> check the checkbox option "Use parent process directory"**. 

Answer (score 15):

1. Open the windows terminal
2. Click the dropdown button
3. Click the settings option
4. set the `startingDirectory` value to `"./"`

Example

```json
"profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
            "startingDirectory": "./" <---- set this value
        }
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: I tried this in the Windows Terminal and it didn't work. I am using Ubuntu with WSL2 and it didn't exited on startup of a new tab (with Ubuntu) with an error.

Comment: This didn't work for me on PowerShell, it sets the starting directory to System32

Comment: This solution, doesn't work. -1

Comment: Real solution described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/new-tab-same-directory

Answer (score 12):

#### Zsh

If you are using Zsh, you can add this to `~/.zshrc`

```
[[ -n "$WT_SESSION" ]] && {
  chpwd() {
    echo -en '\e]9;9;"'
    wslpath -w "$PWD" | tr -d '\n'
    echo -en '"\x07'
  }
}
```

After that, you can use duplicate tab in Windows Terminal to open the same directory in new tab

---

#### Bash

You can also do similar thing in Bash

```
my_prompt() {
  echo -en '\e]9;9;"'
  wslpath -w "$PWD" | tr -d '\n'
  echo -en '"\x07'
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=my_prompt
```

---

#### Explanation

`$WT_SESSION` is an environment set by Windows Terminal. This will ensure we define this escape sequence only in WT.

`chpwd()` is a callback function that Zsh will invoke whenever it changes the working directory.

Inside the `chpwd()` it will send a `OSC 9;9` escape sequence. This will tell the terminal (many terminals including Windows Terminal) that the CWD of the shell has been changed.

The syntax of `OSC 9;9` escape sequence is `\e]9;9;"C:\Temp\"\x07`

The `C:\Temp\` in the sequence has to be Windows-style path. It can point to some path in WSL (e.g. `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\superman\bin`). When opening new tab, the shells will open corresponding UNIX path (e.g. `/home/superman/bin`).

Comment: This is currently the only answer, that currently fixes this issue. It is furthermore very well explained.

Comment: for fish shell this can be achieved with: function storePathForWindowsTerminal --on-variable PWD
    if test -n "$WT_SESSION"
      printf "\e]9;9;%s\e\\" (wslpath -w "$PWD")
    end
end

Answer (score 11):

The Windows Terminal command line interface (`wt.exe`) can be used to achieve this, but with a command instead of a keyboard shortcut.

```
wt -w 0 nt -d .
```

- `-w 0`: Use the current terminal window.
- `nt` or `new-tab`: Create a new tab.

  - `-d .`: Start the process in the current directory.

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments

Comment: Note that this works on windows and opens your default profile, but seems to be ignored in WSL

Comment: But you can launch WSL _from_ powershell using something like `wt -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu -d .`

Answer (score 7):

This is not currently possible, as explained here https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1437 the issue is closed at the moment but could perhaps be re-opened in future.

Comment: update - this is now being tracked under this issue, the spec hasn't been agreed upon at time of writing https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3158

Comment: this is possible right now using `OSC 9;9` sequence. please check the answer below to see how to do that

Answer (score 4):

I've found something interesting.... This worked for me... You can put:

"startingDirectory": "./"

In the terminal configuration....

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciSD2.png)

```
{
    // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile.
    "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "name": "Windows PowerShell",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe",
    "startingDirectory": "./",
    "hidden": false
},
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Answers should not be screenshots, please post code in a codeblock. Also this answer shows how to to open a tab the current directory not the cuurent directory of previous tab as the user asks.

Comment: Unfortunately this only lets you determine the starting directory, it doesn't copy the previous directory when opening a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can always rewrite setting json evertime you open a tab but its a shell specific hack.

Put this function into `$PROFILE` (make sure to adjust `$path`)

```bsh
function sd {
  $path = 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json'
   ((Get-Content -path $path) -replace '"startingDirectory":.*', ("`"startingDirectory`": `"$pwd`"") -replace "\\", "\\") | Set-Content -Path $path
}
```

Solution taken from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3158#issuecomment-654539219).

Answer (score 1):

```sh
dotnet tool install -g p2u
p2u dir ${PWD}
```

Then `CTRL+SHIFT+D`
Hopefully it will work with split pane as well

Same idea of @apena but now with a dotnet tool. For further details: https://github.com/celsojr/p2u

Comment: A simple CTLS+SHIFT+D did the trick for me - what I was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Also a similar vein as @apena's post as it is specific to bash.

In my case I wanted Debian to open on my current working directory.

Although I couldn't exactly get this behavior I was able to get it to open the last directory visited (effectively) using a few hacks:

In my linux distro, I added this to my `.bashrc` to intercept all calls to `cd` and store the last call to `cd` into a destination of my choice.

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@" ;  echo $PWD > /opt/chdir/lastestdir
}
```

Next, since Windows Terminal didn't let me inline the command, I created this batch script to in a custom location:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%n IN (\\wsl$\Debian\opt\chdir\lastestdir) DO @(wsl.exe -d Debian --cd \\wsl$\Debian%%n)
```

NOTE: `\\wsl$\Debian` is the path to my distro within Powershell, and the `\opt\chdir\lastestdir` is based on the path I used in the previous step.

Next, I edited the profile for Debian in Windows terminal to point at my script:
[image: WT Debian profile]

I'm open for suggestions, but this let me happily duplicate my current directory to the next tab as long as it was the last terminal I had changed directory in.